# Validation on Rails 4 virtual attribute array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a virtual attribute array known as attachments in my rails 4 app. I declare it as virtual attribute in the model:

```
class ModelName
attr_accessor :attachments
```

I do validation on that using validate_presence_of

```
 validates_presence_of :attachments
```

attachements is actually set of checkboxes in the page:

```
<input class="attachments" id="attachments_" name="attachments[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Because it is an array, I add it as a hash in the strong parameter: Source: 
http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters

The problem is, I keep getting error message saying attachments can't be blank even if I select a checkbox in the array. What am I doing wrong? If I debug, at the model level, I see that attachments fields is null

Code from my form:

```
   <% (0..4).each do |index| %>
   <label class="checkbox-inline reduce_left_margin">
    <%= check_box_tag 'attachments[]', model::constant_array[index], false, class: 'attachments' %>
    <%= model::constant_array[index][0..2] %>
   </label>
   <% end %>
```

strong params:

```
def allow_params      
    params.require(:model_name).permit(:name,...., :attachments => [:text])     
end
```

Solution:

My strong params were incorrect, had to set it as follows:

```
def allow_params      
    params.require(:model_name).permit(:name,...., :attachments => [])     
end
```

Comment: Can I see code from your form?

Comment: @neo I have added the code from my form to my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you also show your action code with the strong parameter part? If you debug the controller, can you see the `attachments` value from `params`?

Comment: @RPinel: I have added strong parameter section as well

Comment: Have you tried just `params.require(:model_name).permit(:name,...., :attachments)` without the `:text`

Comment: Thank you RPinel. params.require(:model_name).permit(:name,...., :attachments => []) worked for me :)